# Change DataSet on RecyclerView item click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a project in which I need to change data of recyclerView after recyclerView item is clicked. I have tried setOnClickListener in onBindViewHolder method:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Dataset> mDataset = Collections.emptyList();
    private static Context sContext;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

    // Create new views (invoked by layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = null;

        sharedPrefs = Functions.getShPreferences(parent.getContext(), "selected_view");
        viewType = sharedPrefs.getInt("selected_view", 0);
        switch (viewType) {
            case 0:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
                break;
            case 1:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_view, parent, false);
                break;
        }

        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        final Dataset current = mDataset.get(position);

        holder.mName.setText(current.getName());
        holder.mIcon.setImageResource(current.getIconId());
        holder.mLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // make your click listener here
                String f = Functions.getRoot(current.getFile());

                mDataset = Functions.getData(f);
                new FileAdapter(sContext, f);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), f, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mName;
        ImageView mIcon;
        RelativeLayout mLayout;
        //TextView mFileDateModified;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_layout);
            mName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.file_name);
            mIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.file_icon);


        }
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String ph) {
        context = sContext;
        mDataset = Functions.getData(ph);
    }
}
```

I have put this code in onBindViewHolder. But its not working. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what does *But its not working* mean ?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is I'm trying to change data by calling adapter but it's not working

Comment: `holder.layout.setOnClickListener` should be inside your adapter, am I wrong ?

Comment: cool. What is the purpose of `new FileAdapter()` ?

Comment: I need to call the same adapter again to change data inside my recyclerView layout, am I wrong?

Comment: yes you are. Would you mind posting the whole adapter ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81028/discussion-between-apurva-and-blackbelt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your listener in your ViewHolder inner class. Code would be like;

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mDataset = Functions.getData();
        new FileAdapter();
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        // or
        position = getLayoutPosition();
        // both worked for me
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get my current data object in this?

Comment: use `getPosition()` in your onClick method

Comment: getPosition() is depreciated

Comment: ops, okay! looks like you should use either `getLayoutPosition()` or `getAdapterPosition()` based on this page: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html

Comment: where did you use it? i tried both of them in `onClick` method and they worked fine.

Comment: I used it in `onClick` in `ViewHolder` class. I also called layout manager after getting NPE but still got NPE

Comment: Sorry! I was making a mistake in viewHolder. It worked now. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Should call notifyDataSetChanged() in ViewHolder. Might result in an ClassCastException error.

Answer (score 0):

I think calling `notifyDataSetChanged();`
 is not a good idea because it changes and refreshes all the data which might get you into trouble if there are long data so recommend using

```
notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
```

My ViewHolder Looks Like This:

```
public class AttendanceListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView rollNo, name,isPresent;


    public AttendanceListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        if (isRecyclerViewClickable) {
            isPreset.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



        data.get(getAdapterPosition()).wasPresent = "false";


        notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```